# Coldfusion Rest Services Timeout and Throws 500 error after running successfully

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am attempting to create a Restful API on a subdomain (api.mySite.com). I have my cfcs in there with a very basic application file that uses `restInitApplication(pathToRoot, 'api')` to initiate. Everything works great. I can make a call to the cfc `//api.mySite.com/rest/api/cfcRestPath/{Username}` and returns the expected data "**for about an hour or 2**" then all of a sudden I get a 500 error.

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
```

At this point, if I run `restInitApplication()` again, everything is fine and dandy.

How can I make it so that once I initiate it, it will continue to work? The only thing I can think to do is setup a cron job that will refresh the rest service once every hour but that's kind of ghetto.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find that every time you make a change to your REST CFCs that you need to do an app restart. Could this be what you're experiencing? There's a bug raised for this, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Yes adam you are correct. I have also experienced the `500 internal server error` while working with REST. As sean mentioned the issue gets fixed when we call restInitApplication() again.